# How to implement biased random function?

Tags: python

My question is about `random.choice` function. As we know, when we run `random.choice(['apple','banana'])`, it will return either `'apple'` or `'banana'` with equal probabilities, what if I want to return biased result, for example, rerurn `'apple'` with 0.9 probability and `'banana'` with 0.1 probability? How to implement this?

Comment: Put 9 more apples in the array?

Comment: `['apple', 'banana'][random.random()>0.9]`

Comment: @falsetru that's goddamn brilliant, I love it (true to your username I see, no pun intended)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is to create a new list with more of or less of that certain element 
you wan't to biase

This ought to do it:

```
import random

a = ['apple','banana']
probability = [0.1,0.9]

def biase(lst,probability):
    zipped = zip(lst,probability)
    lst = [[i[0]] * int(i[1]*100) for i in zipped]
    new = [b for i in lst for b in i]
    return new

biased_list = biase(a,probability)
random_word = random.choice(biased_list)
print random_word
```

This code will produce `banana` in most cases because the string `banana` is repeated 90% than `apple`

**I've added a list called probability and I've zipped *(python lists are ordered)* it but a dictionary is more suitable for these sort of tasks**

---

And if you go under the hood and print `biased_list` you'll see something like:

```
['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana']
```

Comment: This code sounds more reasonable. With small modifications, it can also applied to more biased elements in a list.

Comment: @petercai True the efficiency and use of this code can be increased, `also consider the use of dictionaries & or sets` BTW *no upvote :(*

Answer (score 6):

Luckily, in Python 3, you can simply use

```
import random
random.choices(a, probability)
#random.choices(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1)
```

Comment: That is correct, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices

Comment: Really useful. Just to put an example: `random.choices(mylist, weights = [10, 1, 1], k = 1)[0]`.

Answer (score 4):

A basic way would be to get a rand number between 0 and 1 and make some test:

```
randNumber = random.random()
if randNumber < 0.9:
     fruit = "apple"
else:
     fruit = "banana"
```

which can be simplified by: `['apple', 'banana'][random.random()>0.9]` (thanks to @falsetru comment)

Comment: It workes with two biased elements, but as the number of biased elements is larger than two, there is no way to extend this code. So I prefer to take the solution posted by `K DawG`.